# Cannot make Java Package on an OpenVZ container

Tags: debian, openvz, proxmox, java

I'm trying to install **Sun's Java SDK 7** by following the Debian Wiki instructions using [java-package](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage). But it won't work on an OpenVZ proxmox container.

I'm running Debian Wheezy 7.0-2 64bit on all my environments.

`java-package` works fine on my local machine and on other virtualized Debian machines ( KVM or VirtualBox) but not on my container.

When I try to `make-jpkg jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz` I get the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Anyone know how to solve this or is it just one of those things that cannot be done in a container?

Comment: Can you run `gunzip` against the package and it works?

Comment: @NathanC: No, it says `gzip: jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz: not in gzip format` perhaps it's a corrupt file? BUt I tried downloading it three times.

Comment: Try `file jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz` and see what it outputs. Maybe `tar -xzf jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz`?

Comment: pft! Please put that as the answer so I can give you credit. `file` said it was an HTML file. wget was downloading some HTML handler for the download instead of the file itself. So I nano'd the file and sure enough: `<html>...` Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the file you were working with was corrupted and not an actual `tar.gz` file. Redownload it via another method (even using something like `lynx`) and it will work.